# plot ROC curve for neural network classifier using perfcurve

Tags: matlab, neural-network, roc

I have been using the patternnet classifier to classify between 2 different classes - labeled 0, 1.
I'm trying to use MATLAB to generate Roc Curve graphs for some data produced using patternnet but I am having trouble understanding the parameters it needs to run.

```
[xTr, yTr, TTr, aucTr] = perfcurve(t, results.Data.y, 1);
```

I assume that:
t is the vector of labels generated that states into which class my data belongs (mine consists of 0 and 1 and is 2x834 in size)
scores is the variable created by patternnet called ‘results.Data.y' (2x834 in size)
posclass is 1.
But scores should be a vector (1x834 in size) and I don't know which row to choose?

Answer (score 0):

Detail about the perfcurve function is available here : 
http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/perfcurve.html
The examples are pretty helpful.

Regarding your specific case, t is not the predicted vector, but the vector you create yourself to label your test data, which obviously would be 1xn (where n = 834 for your case.)

Your score matrix would be m*n, where m is the number of classes in your data (which is 2 for your case).
Since you're saying 1 is your positive class, you'll chose the column which contains the score of your positive class.
Something like :

```
[xTr, yTr, TTr, aucTr] = perfcurve(t, results.Data.y(:,1), 1);
plot(xTr, yTr);
```

Comment: Thanks. Then, I would appreciate if could explain me some part of the following code:
(http://lamda.nju.edu.cn/code_CSNN.ashx)
 
In LableFormatConvertion.m file,  line  50:
'prediction=ClassType(id);'. @ArchitTaneja

Comment: @ebrahimi I am not sure what 'label' exactly is in the input, but to answer your question:
when you find 'id' using max(Label), you get row indices of Label, where the max element appears:
eg :for 
    A = [1 9 -2; 8 4 -5], id would be [2, 1, 1] which represents that in the first column, 8 is maximum, and it's row index is 2.
Now you have a tuple as 'id'. Using the values in 'id' you access the array elements of ClassType.
For eg :
If your 'id' is [2,1,1] and ClassType is [0,1]
'prediction' would be [1,0,0] . i.e id(1) =2 fetches ClassType(2) =1, id(2)=1 would fetch ClassType(1) = 0 and so on.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, there is six algorithms to deal with unbalanced classification. For example, consider oversampling and then, please look at sample_oversampling. m file, so it is clear what label is. It is the simulated output for test data. My problem is that if we change ClassType to [1,0], then the result would be the reverse and how it is known which one is correct to do  [0, 1] or [1, 0]. @ArchitTaneja

Comment: Sorry for being a little late.
There is nothing wrong with either [0,1] or [1,0]
It is just a matter of which class being is labelled as 1, and which is being labelled as 0.
Eg :  You have classes A and B, and you can chose either of it to be represented by 1, and then chose.